# Insertar salto de linea y que no se pueda seleccionar elemento en un <select>

Tags: html, css

Hola estoy haciendo una lista de elementos en un `<select>` y quiero dividir las opciones.

Para esto quiero que se muestren diferentes 'categorias' como titulo (el cual no se podría seleccionar). El problema es que ya intenté lo convencional para dar saltos de linea en HTML y no me ha funcionado. ¿Tienen alguna idea de cómo hacerlo?

Mi idea es que la lista quede así al desplegarse:

> ```
> Categoría 1 <-- Este elemento no se puede seleccionar  
> Elemento seleccionable  
> Elemento seleccionable  
> Elemento seleccionable  
> Elemento seleccionable  
>
> Categoría 2 <-- Este elemento no se puede seleccionar  
> Elemento seleccionable  
> Elemento seleccionable  
> Elemento seleccionable  
> Elemento seleccionable  
>
> Categoría 3 <-- Este elemento no se puede seleccionar  
> Elemento seleccionable  
> Elemento seleccionable  
> Elemento seleccionable  
> Elemento seleccionable
> ```

Como referencia les pongo este sitio donde hacen algo parecido:
[Convert World](http://www.convertworld.com/es/).

No les pido que me diseñen la lista, solo quiero saber cómo aplicar el salto de linea y los elementos que no se pueden seleccionar.

Comment: el enlace que tu hhas mandado, esta echo con bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para incluir "saltos de línea" no tienes más que poner en el `select` elementos `option` sin texto.

Para evitar que algunos elementos se puedan seleccionar utiliza el atributo `disabled` en el `option`.

```html
<select>
<option disabled>Categoría 1</option>
<option>Elemento seleccionable</option>
<option>Elemento seleccionable</option>
<option>Elemento seleccionable</option>
<option>Elemento seleccionable</option>
<option disabled></option>
<option disabled>Categoría 2</option>
<option>Elemento seleccionable</option>
<option>Elemento seleccionable</option>
<option>Elemento seleccionable</option>
<option>Elemento seleccionable</option>
<option disabled></option>
<option disabled>Categoría 3</option>
<option>Elemento seleccionable</option>
<option>Elemento seleccionable</option>
<option>Elemento seleccionable</option>
<option>Elemento seleccionable</option>
</select>
```

Otra opción es utilizar `optgroup`:

```html
<select>
    <optgroup label="Categoría 1">
    <option>Elemento seleccionable</option>
    <option>Elemento seleccionable</option>
    <option>Elemento seleccionable</option>
    <option>Elemento seleccionable</option>
    </optgroup>
    <option disabled></option>
    <optgroup label="Categoría 2">
    <option>Elemento seleccionable</option>
    <option>Elemento seleccionable</option>
    <option>Elemento seleccionable</option>
    <option>Elemento seleccionable</option>
    </optgroup>
    <option disabled></option>
    <optgroup label="Categoría 3">
    <option>Elemento seleccionable</option>
    <option>Elemento seleccionable</option>
    <option>Elemento seleccionable</option>
    <option>Elemento seleccionable</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: En lugar de dos `option disabled` quizá podría emplear `optgroup`

Comment: Cierto. Edito la respuesta para incluir un ejemplo con `optgroup`